# Loading HTML in the current dom and execute a loaded script

Tags: dart, dart-html, dart-isolates

In javascript I created a loader for a wizard. I talk about a single page with a wizard section.

Every (new) sequence state of the page loads a HTML section from the server into the wizard dom section of the page and executes a script. The script for this sequence state is also loaded.

I have seen a lot of discussion about loading Dart scripts and [this blog](http://blog.sethladd.com/2013/04/dynamically-load-code-with-dart.html?m=1) post from Sett Ladd. I understand I can only load Dart scripts in isolates.

My questions:

1. Can I create the above like wizard in Dart?
2. When I load a script in an isolate, can I access the "current" page dom?

Comment: for 2) I believe it's no, you can only pass a message back to the main isolate which can itself update or see the dom.

Comment: I found : spawnDomUri (Experimental) : https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/stable/dartdoc-viewer/dart-dom-html#id_spawnDomUri no docs and some issues.